# Is $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ separable for the railmetric( or SNCF -metric or post-office metric)?

Tags: analysis

> It's the follow metric: $d(x,y)= ||x|| +||y||$ if $x$ and $y$ don't lie on a line through the origin. And otherwise $d(x,y)= ||x-y||$.
>
> I think  the answer is no, because I tried it with $\mathbb{Q}^{2}$ as countable and that didn't work. But I don't know how to prove it that it isn't true in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: You're right: it's not. You can prove it by finding an uncountable family of pairwise disjoint, non-empty open sets. I've added a further hint in the spoiler-protected block below.

> Consider open rays leaving the origin.

Comment: Yes , I'm sorry, I reversed the conditions.

Comment: Ok, thanks. But I don't understand the hint that good. Could you explain it a bit more?

Comment: @jens: Did you also look at the hidden hint?

Comment: yes I did. But I have to prove that there is no countable dense set, why I have to find an uncountable family?

Comment: @jens: Suppose that $D$ is a dense set. Every one of those open sets has to contain a member of $D$. Can $D$ then be countable?

Comment: No, it can't. But all these rays, are they uncountable? How do you know?

Comment: @jens: There's a ray for each real number in the interval $[0,2\pi)$. (Think polar coordinates.) All non-trivial intervals of real numbers are uncountable.

Comment: Ah yes of course , ok. And then its proofed?

Comment: @jens: Yes, at that point you have all of the necessary ingredients.

Comment: Can you also consider just points on these rays and because D is dense, on every ray there have to be a point of D near that point. And because there are uncountable isolated points, D must uncountable. But aren't they isolated?

Comment: @jens: There are no isolated points in this space.